# Number of weeks in financial years (UK)

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, national-insurance, payroll

For each of the last 15 years, in the UK how many weeks were there in the tax/financial year? I want to have a clear out of old payslips and plan on shredding them all apart from the last one of each financial year.

I know that some financial years will have been 53 weeks long rather then 52 weeks long.

Comment: Would keeping your P60s be an alternative?

Comment: I've got more years worth of pay slips than P60s (think some of my P60s may have gotten caught up with previous paperwork that I've shredded)

Comment: Why would you want more than 6 years' worth anyway?

Comment: Why not shred anything that isn't week 52 or 53? You'll be left with at most 30 to sort through.

Answer (score 1):

Every year has 53 weeks as there are no years with only 364 days `(52 * 7)`

If you are paid weekly you may have only 52 payslips in a particular year – but as to which years, this depends on which day of the week your payslip is issued.

Comment: OP is asking about a specific convention in a specific jurisdiction.  This answer misunderstands the question.

Comment: @user662852 : I don't think it does misunderstand the question. HMRC does have a standard convention for tax weeks and there are always 53 in a tax year. But whether an individual, paid weekly, would actually have received pay in all 53 of those weeks in a given year will depend on whether 5th April (and 4th April in a leap year) happens to fall on the day of the week they get paid or not.